# Ignoring property when deserializing

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a simple interface with getter and setter for a property.

```
public interface HasMoney { 

      Money getMoney();

      void setMoney(Money money);

 }
```

I have another class UserAccount which implements this interface.

```
public class UserAccount implements HasMoney {

       private Money money;

       @Override
       Money getMoney() // fill in the blanks

       @Override
       void setMoney(Money money) // fill in the blanks

}
```

My problem is that I want to serialize the money property but ignore while deserializing it i.e., dont accept any values from the user for this property. I have tried @JsonIgnore on setter and @JsonIgnore(false) on the getter, it does ignore it but it does so while serializing it also.

I tried @JsonIgnore on the setter and @JsonProperty on the getter just to explicitly tell Jackson that we intend to track this property, that seems to crash the application when money property is sent to the server and Jackson tries to deserialize it throwing up MalformedJsonException : cannot construct object of type Money.

The most wierd thing is that putting @JsonIgnore on the setter and @JsonProperty on the setter works for most cases when the property is primitive.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok, so the behavior of @JsonIgnore was radically changed from 1.9 onwards (for the worse imo). Without going into the devilish details of why your property is not being ignore during deserialization, try this code to fix it:

```
public class UserAccount implements HasMoney {
    @JsonIgnore
    private BigDecimal money;

    // Other variable declarations, constructors

    @Override
    @JsonProperty
    public BigDecimal getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public void setMoney(final BigDecimal money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    // Other getters/setters
}
```

Note the use of `@JsonIgnore` on the field - its required for a working solution.

*Note: depending on your environment and use case, you may need additional configuration on your ObjectMapper instance, for example,* USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS, AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS, AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS *etc*.

Comment: This is actually part of the solution. I also had to add objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS) and it worked then. Please edit your answer and I will accept it. Its sad that there is no cleaner way to this (Atleast I was not able to find it ).

Comment: @NishantNagwani - odd, works for me without that feature enabled. I'm adding an optional note to my answer but I'm curious if something is different about your setup that would necessitate `USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS`.

Comment: I tried it again. Doesnt work with my environment. I am using jackson 2.1.1 . Here is the error I get

{
    "message": "Malformed json passed to server, incorrect data type used: \nProblem deserializing 'setterless' property 'money': get method returned null (through reference chain: com.abc.def.Money])"
}

Comment: Please join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28334/ignoring-property-when-deserializing).

Answer (score 78):

Version 2.6.0+ allows this to be done with @JsonIgnoreProperties at the class level.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value={ "money" }, allowGetters=true)
```

Take a look at this closed issue:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/95

Comment: This solution is cleaner

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient solution, thank you!

Comment: This also works with immutable kotlin data classes.

Comment: This was the only working solution, when using Lombok, because then I don't have code for getters/setter to put annotations on (like accepted answer).

Comment: @Somnium I'm glad you liked my answer. As a note, if you define your own getters/setters, Lombok won't generate its own. This allows you to write getters/setters for certain fields, decorate these methods with annotations, then let Lombok generate the other getters/setters.

Comment: At class level you can only do one value. Therefore, if you want to have multiple values ignored, in one classes properties, you have to put one such line on each property to ignore.

Comment: @Beezer The class level annotation accepts multiple values. They need to be comma separated, like so

@JsonIgnoreProperties(value={ "money", "year" }, allowGetters=true)

Comment: I tried that, no dice. Thanks all the same. I am using Jackson version 2.10.2...soooo...:=(

Comment: I'm on the same version (Jackson core 2.10.2 with the latest spring boot) and it worked for me. You should see the values always deserialized as null. I'll try to create an example project to show you what I'm seeing

Comment: @Beezer take a look at 
https://github.com/kmek91/jacksonDeserializationDemo
I've included two kinds of tests. One where I create an ObjectMapper and invoke readValue manually (ManualTests.java) and one where I start the Spring Boot app and send a request to the Controller to see what Spring deserializes the payload as (ControllerTests). All tests pass and ignored fields are ignored. Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks...I will give it another shot...@kmek :=)

Comment: This is also correct solution for scala case class

Comment: Quite inconvenient that this is not the default for Kotlin lazy properties...

Answer (score 13):

With Jackson 2.10 you can implement a read-only field like this:

### A real field

```java
public class UserAccount implements HasMoney {

   @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
   private Money money;
   
   // getter and setter

}
```

### A virtual field

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) // to ignore ALL unknown properties
// OR
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"money"}, allowGetters = true) // to ignore only 'money' input
public class UserAccount implements HasMoney {

   @JsonProperty
   public Money getMoney() {
       // some calculation
   }

}
```

The value will be serialized but ignored during deserialization.

Comment: How is this different than my answer? The key is JsonIgnoreProperties which was updated in version 2.6.0 to work as detailed above. I don't think the JsonProperty with READ_ONLY access does anything for this problem.

Comment: If the field has a default value it will not be changed during deserialization. Even if JSON contains a new value for it.
The annotation JsonProperty with READ_ONLY tells deserializer to keep the old value of the property during deserialization.

Answer (score 6):

In a case of you don't own or can't change the class by adding `@JsonIgnore` annotation, you would get expected result by using mixin starting from version *2.5* in your implementation.

```
public abstract class HasMoneyMixin {
    @JsonIgnore
    public abstract Money getMoney();
}
```

configure mapper to use mixin,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(HasMoney.class, HasMoneyMixin.class);
// avoid failing if all properties are empty
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently my solution is late, but definitely will be helpful for others.

**Prehistory**:
in my project there is a class reading a JSON string directly into an entity. The JSON contains a property which is not a variable of the class. Because of

```
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

an instance of the entity will not be created during deserialization (an exception in such a case is desired in our project).

**Solution**:

```
objectMapper.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext ctxt, JsonParser p, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer, Object beanOrClass, String propertyName) throws IOException {
       if( (propertyName.equals("propertyToBeIgnored") && beanOrClass.getClass().equals(ClassOfTheProperty.class)) {
           p.skipChildren();
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: With `ctxt.getConfig().introspect(ctxt.constructType(beanOrClass.getClass()))` you can get bean's description (detected props, getters, setters, etc.).