# Jackson: avoid deserialization of some fields but not ignoring them

Tags: java, json, jackson

i need to carry all the json data (to store them, log, return) but i will never access them from code. is there any way to avoid deserializing them but still use them during serialization?

```
class MyObject {    
  int importantField; // i want this field to be properly deserialized
  String notImportantJsonGarbage; // i don't care what's here. it must be a valid json
}
```

So now i'd like to be able to deserialize it from

```
{"importantField":7, "notImportantJsonGarbage":{"key1":3, "key2":[1,2,3]}}
```

and later serialize it to the same string

**UPDATE**

i don't want to ignore this property. i need this data. but as a string, not fully deserialized object

i need to be able to do:

```
json1 -> object -> json2
json1 == json2
```

Comment: Did you try using JSONObject type as I have mentioned  in my answer? I think that solves your problem. You can read that to a json object and deserialize it only when needed.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019834/ignoring-property-when-deserializing/65329163#65329163) on an another deserialization question may be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at: [JsonProperty.Access](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html)

> - **AUTO** -     Access setting which means that visibility rules are to be used    to automatically determine read- and/or write-access of
>     this    property.
> - **READ_ONLY** - Access setting that means that the property may    only be read for serialization, but not written (set) during
>     deserialization.
> - **READ_WRITE** - Access setting that means that the    property will be accessed for both serialization (writing out values    as
>     external representation) and deserialization (reading values from
>     external representation), regardless of visibility rules.
> - **WRITE_ONLY** -     Access setting that means that the property may only be written (set)    for deserialization, but will not be read
>     (get) on serialization,    that is, the value of the property is not
>     included in serialization.

So in your case you could use it like this:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private String notImportantJsonGarbage;
```

Comment: but this way `notImportantJsonGarbage` is `null`. therefore information is missing and my requirement **and later serialize it to the same string** is not fulfilled

Comment: This works for simple field types, but in my experience fails for fields such as a collection or list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type [JSONObject](http://javadox.com/org.json/json/20151123/org/json/package-summary.html) for the Json field.

```
private JSONObject notImportantJsonGarbage;
```

And when you need to read that, you can convert it to a String (or other type). You can use `jackson` or `gson` libraries to achieve that.

Note that when you convert the `JsonObject` back to `String`, the resulting string might have the quotes escaped.

Using JSONObject also solves your requirement of 'must be a valid json object'.