# How to make Jackson not to write to @GeneratedValue fields?

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson, jax-rs

I'm using JPA, Jackson and JAX-RS in the following way.

My entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
}
```

This class has no setter for `id` because it's auto generated. Even if I put the setter there is no difference. I don't mind having it if Jackson needs it but it shouldn't be used anyway.

This is the resource:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.test.persons.entity.Person;

@Path("persons")
public class PersonResource {

    @Inject
    PersonService service;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response save(JsonObject inputPerson) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Person person = null;
        try {
            person = mapper.readValue(inputPerson.toString(), Person.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        service.save(person); // calls @PersistenceContext EntityManager#persist(person)
        return Response.ok(person).build();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `inputPerson` comes with its own `id` which should be ignored and `person` should have auto generated its own `id`. But Jackson uses the `id` from `inputPerson` which results in an exception in the JPA layer (because the `@Id` is wrong).

What I want is just to create a `Person` object with the properties of the given `Person` in `JsonObject` form and with its auto generated id. How can I achieve that?

Note that I when I serialize a `Person` to Json `String` with

```
String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
```

I do need the `id` to be serialized. Just not deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your field `id` with `@JsonIgnore` annotation, this way Jackson Json will completely ignore this field.

Upd.
If you want to ignore that field when you deserialize object, but use it when you serialize it, `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` could be useful. Or you can try to annotate setter with `@JsonIgnore.`

Comment: But when I write the Person to JSON format will it also be ignored? I added a note at the end.

Comment: Yes, then you can use @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)

Comment: I'm getting errors in Eclipse: `Multiple markers at this line
 -The attribute access is undefined for the annotation type 
  JsonProperty
 -WRITE_ONLY cannot be resolved or is not a field` Maybe the version is old? How do I check? I'm using Wildfly 10.1.

Comment: What happens when you add @JsonIgnore on setter instead of the field itself?

Comment: Checking. it looks like it's ignoring the id both on read and write. though i understand that since we didn't annotate the getter it shouldn't happen. let me dig a bit. thanks.

Comment: Yes. I can confirm id is not being serialized as well. so now deser. works but ser. broke.

Comment: Ah, I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019834/ignoring-property-when-deserializing. Very unintuitive. No idea why that's what needs to be done. I don't even need the setter at all.