# Jackson JSONDeserialize + Builder with different field name?

Tags: jackson, json-deserialization

I'm pretty new to using Jackson and I'm trying to follow my team's patterns for deserializing our JSON. Right now I am running into an issue when a field name doesn't match the JSON property.

Working example:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ProfilePrimaryData.Builder.class)
@Value
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
private static class ProfilePrimaryData {
    private final Boolean hasProfile;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class Builder {
    }
}
```

If the JSON property is hasProfile, it works fine, but if it's has_profile (which is what our client is writing), it doesn't work and I get an error: `Unrecognized field "has_profile" (class com.mypackagehere.something.$ProfilePrimaryData$Builder), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "hasProfile"])`. I've tried adding a JsonProperty annotation to hasProfile like this but it still doesn't work:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ProfilePrimaryData.Builder.class)
@Value
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
private static class ProfilePrimaryData {
    @JsonProperty("has_profile")
    private final Boolean hasProfile;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class Builder {
    }
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019834/ignoring-property-when-deserializing

or

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "has_profile" })`  class level annotation

or to be more generic

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: @SASIKUMARS - I don't think we're on the same page - I want the has_profile field to be read in and put into the hasProfile field in the POJO. Wouldn't JsonIgnoreProperties just throw the value away?

Comment: can you post the sample JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error clearly says that `Unrecognized field "has_profile" (class com.mypackagehere.something.$ProfilePrimaryData$Builder`)
i.e `has_profile`  is missing from `Builder` class, not `ProfilePrimaryData` class, so you have to annotate Builder class properties.

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ProfilePrimaryData.Builder.class)
public class ProfilePrimaryData {

    /*
     * This annotation only needed, if you want to
     * serialize this field as has_profile,
     * 
     * <pre>
     * with annotation
     * {"has_profile":true}
     * 
     * without annotation
     * {"hasProfile":true}
     * <pre>
     *  
     */
    //@JsonProperty("has_profile")
    private final Boolean hasProfile;

    private ProfilePrimaryData(Boolean hasProfile) {
        this.hasProfile = hasProfile;
    }

    public Boolean getHasProfile() {
        return hasProfile;
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class Builder {

        // this annotation is required
        @JsonProperty("has_profile")
        private Boolean hasProfile;

        public Builder hasProfile(Boolean hasProfile) {
            this.hasProfile = hasProfile;
            return this;
        }

        public ProfilePrimaryData build() {
            return new ProfilePrimaryData(hasProfile);
        }
    }
}
```